# Is my Cloud Firestore db safe without guarding rules if project-id is completely oblique?

Tags: android, google-cloud-filestore

I am creating an Android app for many people to share certain facts that can be interesting also for unwanted eyes. A Cloud Firestore db is used so userA can read what userB has written. The documentation exhorts us to use "narrowing rules" but I think that I am not smart enough to set rules that can stop an even smarter hacker. Rules must be set for a deployed app because "anyone out there who has guessed your project-Id can read and write your data". So if I choose a project-Id that gives no clue to belong to the app?

Answer (score 0):

Security rules provide access control and data validation in a simple yet expressive format. To build user-based and role-based access systems that keep your users' data safe, you need to use Firebase Authentication with Cloud Firestore Security Rules. Security Rules are a must to ensure data safety.
Learn more at - [Official Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)